# How can i merge two dom element collection into third using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i merge two dom element collection into third??
as i have collection of all input element and all select type element now want to merge both collection.

```
var allE = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var allS = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var allES = allE.merge(allS);
```

Comment: You can't, there's no way to create nodeLists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
var selects = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("select"));

var all = inputs.concat(selects);
```

or with jQuery

```
var collection = $('input, select');
```

Comment: it gives me error i already used that..

Comment: A nodeList has no `concat` method, only arrays do

Comment: sorry - my bad, edited :)

Comment: got answer myself:

 var allES = [];
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 allES.push(inputs[i]);
                }

    // gather SELECT elements
             var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
                for ( i=0; i < selects.length; i++){
                    allES.push(selects[i]);
                    }

Comment: Mind you that this does not create a nodeList but an array